# Scipy not working with python 3 but does with 2.6(default)

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I have installed Scipy by build and install from the terminal. But I get the following error when I try to execute the following simple code:

```
from scipy.stats.mstats_basic import gmean

ab=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(gmean(ab))
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/prashanthb/workspace/rankalgo/rough1.py", line 2, in <module>

    from scipy.stats.mstats_basic import gmean

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 321, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 194, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 525, in <module>

ImportError: No module named _cephes
```

But the same code works when I switch to the default interpreter python 2.6. I have installed Libatlas and lapack before and Numpy(already installed under python3) seems to work well.
I have got mpmath installed too.

**Question:** How to proceed from here to get it to work with python3? If anybody knows any other library to calculate geometric mean please do mention.
Thanks in advance
prashanth

UPDATE: I found this while building setup.py it again:

```
DeprecationWarning)

customize GnuFCompiler

Could not locate executable g77

Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelFCompiler

Could not locate executable ifort

Could not locate executable ifc

customize LaheyFCompiler

Could not locate executable lf95

customize PGroupFCompiler

Could not locate executable pgfortran

customize AbsoftFCompiler

Could not locate executable f90

customize NAGFCompiler

Found executable /usr/bin/f95

customize VastFCompiler

customize CompaqFCompiler

Could not locate executable fort

customize IntelItaniumFCompiler

Could not locate executable efort

Could not locate executable efc

customize IntelEM64TFCompiler

customize Gnu95FCompiler

Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using config
compiling '_configtest.c':
```

Comment: scipy.test() shows that nose>=0.10.0 is needed.

Comment: Since scipy has a lot of dependencies it would probably to install a packaged solution for your distribution. Which distribution are you using? Don't you have that option?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10. I checked and did not find any scipy/numpy package.

Comment: You're right. There is no `python3-scipy` package on Ubuntu 10.10. If you have that option I would suggest upgrading Ubuntu to 12.04. That one already has `python3-scipy` packaged and it will make your live much easier (Ubuntu 10.10 is no longer supported at this point in time).